# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'BusinessLogic' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

Like lot of people, I got CS0103 issue, but I've not found a good solution on the existing topics when working with IIS7.5

The strange thing is:

- The site is **working fine under IIS5.1 / XP** (at least, there is not this issue)
- The site is working fine under IIS7.5 Express / XP (when running from Visual Studio 2010)
- The site is **working fine under IIS7.5 Express / W7** (when running from Visual Studio 2010)
- But I've got this error when using IIS7.5 / W7

The class involved in this error is in BusinessLogicWrapper.cs, in the App_Code folder (which **icon is grey in Visual Studio**. Does that mean it is not taken into account? Or it's only because it's a special folder?).

I tried to add at the beginning of SessionProcessing.ashx an `include BusinessLogic;` but it has not working: the compiler just stop at the 3rd line instead of the 30th, saying it does not know what it has to include...

I thank you for your help,

---

More information:

- I am running a Precompiled version of the website
- At the beginning it has been designed for IIS5.1

---

**A partial workaround has been to put the bin folder of my virtual directory into the root directory.**

Note that I do not have "server errors" anymore (for the moment at least), but that the website is still not working (I think that there is issues with path to the different files...).

This is not a definitive answer (from myself to myself and the others) but perhaps it could give some ideas to more experimented users!

---

The 500 error shown by the website:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'BusinessLogic' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 28:                                 (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && context.Request.Params["action"] == "DELETE"))
Line 29:                 {
Line 30:                     BusinessLogic.Wrapper.WRITE_TRACE(BusinessLogic.TraceLevel.MEDIUM, "SessionProcessing.ashx End session", "sid:" + sid);
Line 31:                     int res = BusinessLogic.Wrapper.removeSession(sid);
Line 32: 

Source File: c:\Users\blabla\PrecompiledWeb\Web2\SessionProcessing.ashx    Line: 30
```

The beginning of the SessionProcessing.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="getsession" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

public class getsession : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        String sid = context.Request.Params["sessionid"];

        try
        {
            if (sid != null)
            {
                //###############################################
                //###############################################
                if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "DELETE" ||
                                (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && context.Request.Params["action"] == "DELETE"))
                {
                    BusinessLogic.Wrapper.WRITE_TRACE(BusinessLogic.TraceLevel.MEDIUM, "SessionProcessing.ashx End session", "sid:" + sid);
                    int res = BusinessLogic.Wrapper.removeSession(sid);
```

And finally an image of the tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szbhA.png

---

App_Code/BusinessLogicWrapper.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BusinessLogic
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for BusinessLogicWrapper
    /// </summary>
    public class Wrapper
    {
        //Init
        [DllImport("BusinessLogicLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int init(string loginFilePath, string remoteServerName, string[] itemsConnection, int cItems);
```

web.config (In reality, there is 9 rules for rewriting)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpCookies domain="localhost"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- add support for ogg files-->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".oga" mimeType="audio/ogg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".spx" mimeType="audio/ogg"/>
      <!-- <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/> -->
    </staticContent>
    <!--Disable gzip compression (otherwise server pushed data is cut when arriving on the client) -->
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="COW API session creation">
          <match url="^session$"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="SessionProcessing.ashx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding proper namespace for your `BusinessLogic(Wrapper)` class?

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="getsession" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using [YourProjectName].App_Code
```

If it's Web Site project try removing namespace completely in your `BusinessLogicWrapper.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


    public class Wrapper
    {
        //Init
        [DllImport("BusinessLogicLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int init(string loginFilePath, string remoteServerName, string[] itemsConnection, int cItems);
```

Then access your Wrapper class like: `Wrapper.WRITE_TRACE...`

Comment: Thans for your answer!
But the issue is: I do not really have a Project Name 9for what I know), since it is a web application (that's why I get a 500 error).
I tried to just write `using App_Code;`, but since it is not a namespace...
Where could I found my project name (I am really newbie in ASP, and I am working on a project I have not developed)?
Thank you anyway!

Comment: When you say "web application", I believe you mean it's a "Web Site Project" (File->New Web Site). Web Application Projects have namespaces and project names.

Comment: Sorry for not using the appropriate vocabulary. Yes, it's a Web Site Project.

Comment: I add a "partial workaround" in my post, using the root directory. It has solved the compilation error. But the website is still not woking (when I try to login, it does not recognize my identifiers, probably because they are stored in a file and that the relative path from the bin folder to this file has changed)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround (leave comments if you have a better idea) has been to put the bin folder of my virtual directory into the root directory.

Note that I do not have "server errors" anymore (for the moment at least), but that the website is still not working (I think that there is issues with path to the different files...).

This is not a definitive answer (from myself to myself and the others) but perhaps it could give some ideas to more experimented users!

Comment: A functional "workaround" has been to move everything in the root folder, instead of a virtual folder (so the relative links are still working). Of course, the issue is that there is only one root folder, so if I need to deploy other websites...
I am still interested by your solutions!